# preprocessing or real time for magnification of portions of video

Tags: computer-architecture, image-processing, real-time

Im new at CS and would like to gather preliminary information to approach an interactive art project.

I want to construct a grid of videos - think about a matrix *M = m x n* where *Mi,j* is a video that cover a certain portion of the screen.

I want to interact with the screen, so that if I trigger a certain action, the video *Mi,j* got magnified.

Magnification of the video could result in any of:

- the magnified video get superimposed on the neighbors (e.g. *M(i+1,j+1)*, etc. )
- the neighbors are shifted to make space for the magnified video

In order to make the grid, I could make use of FFMPEG, but preprocessing the grid as one single video, could make the second option very cumbersome.

I'd like to know:

- would it possible to align a matrix of videos, without merging them in one object ?
  If so, how to estimate memory issues and limits ?
- which kind of framework would you suggest to learn for this project:
- processing (e.g. tutorials https://timrodenbroeker.de/new-course-copy-and-paste/), pixi.js, openFrameworks, puredata, others ?)

--

settings / requirements

The project aims to be an art installation, made with a computer and a projector.
The user can interact in a room and trigger selection of the *i,j* via an arduino, the projector will project the grid on a wall.
The videos composing the grids could be pre-processed before; I'd like, indeed, to learn how to estimate the limit for applying effects in real time to a *i,j* videos and to align *m x n* videos in a big canvas, and software to look at for designing a prototype of architecture.

Computing skills:
Python, some javascript, absolute begineer in C++

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing your specific usage, I'd use Isadora or TouchDesign for these kind of task. They can help you manipulate realtime feeds based on the events

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I did not even know them, and looking at their websites to learn if they are open source or require commercial license to use and if there is any tutorial to get through. Do you have experience with them ?

Comment: I believe they are commercial products, but you can easily find their open-source alternatives, though you might have to use 2-3 software together to achieve the same goal. Take a look at Vuo and Pure Data please, I haven't used them in production but I believe they are useful. Yes, I have some experiences with them, a couple of experimental Interactive performance shows and some theoretical research. For my purposes Isadora was more lightweight and efficient.